# getAnnotation returns null for multiple annotations

Tags: java

I have a repeatable annotation

```
@Repeatable(Examples.class)
public @interface Example {
    int value();
}
```

With container annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Examples {
    Example[] value();
}
```

Then I try to launch this code

```
@Example(1)
@Example(2)
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = Test.class.getAnnotation(Example.class);
        System.err.println(example);
    }
}
```

However it prints `null`. How does it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should carefully re-read documentation regarding [repeatable annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html). It happens because more than one repeatable annotation is wrapped to container annotation:

> There are several methods available in the Reflection API that can be used to retrieve annotations. The behavior of the methods that return a single annotation, such as [`AnnotatedElement.getAnnotationByType(Class<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-), are unchanged in that they only return a single annotation if one annotation of the requested type is present. If more than one annotation of the requested type is present, you can obtain them by first getting their container annotation.

So you have several options

1. Use `getAnnotationsByType` method

```java
Example[] annotations = Test.class.getAnnotationsByType(Example.class);
```

2. Use `getAnnotation` using container annotation

```java
Example[] annotations = Test.class.getAnnotation(Examples.class).value();
```